# How unsafe is it to ride a bike with this dent in aluminium top tube?

Tags: frames, safety

This didn't happen as part of a crash. In fact, I'm not sure what might be the reason. I just looked down and saw this while riding on a sunny day. My bike is *always* in my room and I live alone. I sit on my top tube from time to time during traffic light waiting. I sometimes descend on top tube. The frame is 23000 KM old. Always by 68-72 KG me. I had crashed before but never hit top tube.

[image: dent right side]

[image: dent top]

[image: dent full bike]

Comment: Keep an eye on it, and don't undertake any transcontinental journeys.  But so long as you're alert for any signs of cracking it should be OK.

Comment: Possibly duplicating https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/77589/would-it-be-fatally-dangerous-to-ride-with-this-dent-pictures Same brand and model too.

Comment: No more supertucking/top tube descending for sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's pretty bad. No one here can tell you the risk of it actually breaking. What can be said is that it were to ever break, odds are it would happen at some outlier moment of extreme stress on the frame, such as unintentionally hitting a bump on a fast descent. What I would not do is make any assumptions that in any scenario where it broke, you'd get meaningful warning in addition to what you already have.

Canyon has a crash replacement program. The world is more pinched for components than frames right now, so they may even have frames to send. It would be wise to look that direction.

Comment: Signed up for crash replacement program. It is pretty good and so far it seems that you are right about frame availability. Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 6):

I did not risk it. Like [Nathan suggested](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/77854/33084), I contacted Canyon and described the situation.

They were kind enough to instruct me to not descend on the top tube and offered a crash replacement frame for 30% or 40% of the original price. I had to send the bike to them for maintenance, so the whole process took several weeks. I'm still riding the bike to this day with the new frame. I still descend on the top tube (though much less), and when I do, I try to keep most of my mass on the pedals instead.